# VB6, Win10 x64, MS Office 2016, the Office (Excel) 16 reference is not available, VB, how to add?

Tags: windows, reference, vb6

As said:
I have a working VB6 installation and also a functional MS Office 16 (2016) package on my Win10 laptop. Everything runs as it should, but:
I cannot reference the EXCEL (or any other office) library in VB for a current small project I am tinkering with. It simply is not listed, "missing in action".

The VB lib menu allows to 'search' for additional libraries, but what/where to grab the missing Office 16 lib? I do recall that all worked for earlier MS Office versions just fine.
A 'Repair' of MS Office 2016 did not fix the issue.

Comment: Do you have the 64 bit version of Office installed? If so its not accessible from VB6.

Comment: You can't reference the 64bit EXCEL, but you can declare some variable as object and use CreateObject("Excel.Application") to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks! After asking I quickly realized that this might be an issue with X64 vs X86, and my Office 16 is indeed a 64bit version.

Comment: I installed the X86 package and can now simply set  an Excel object with  "Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.application")". I sort of remember it being done differently many years ago when I was more involved in this stuff, but all works now perfectly. Thank you!